# How would I take a full inventory (architecture + content) of our entire SharePoint Intranet?

Tags: crawling, provisioning, content-and-structure

We have a **SharePoint 2010** on *Premise environment* that I will be replacing soon - but first I want to just capture an inventory of everything we've currently got inside it. Both the structure of our site collection and sites and subsites, but also all the content that's held in various places.

With **Visio** I can plug in a url and have it spit out a diagram, but this is still going to require a massive amount of work to manually clean it up. Is there a decent way to do something like this automatically from SharePoint??